# D3 remove 'zoom' completely

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

I'm trying to remove zoom completely from a svg.

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(userNodesScaleX)
    .y(userNodesScaleY)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
userMapSvg.call(zoom);
```

And this has added a 'rect.background' to the top of the SVG, which prevent the mouse event from reaching the other elements in the SVG.

So I decide to remove the zoom completely. remove the event, remove that rect. How can I do that?

Current code is

```
removeZoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", null);
```

which doesn't work. It only toggles the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop any future zooming from transforming the page, remove the listener:

```
zoom.on("zoom", null)
```

To undo previous zoom transformations:

```
zoom.scale(1).translate([0,0]).event(userMapSvg)
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/6414125

The buttons at the top of the bl.ocks show both behaviors.

If neither work/are what you're looking for, posting a working example of the problem would be extremely helpful. You might also want to look through the [zoom documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior).

Comment: I'm afraid not, @Adam. I'm exactly using it as mentioned in the question.

Comment: NAZIK & rink.attendant - 'zoom.on("zoom", null)' is an answer to the question, see the link for an example of what it does.

Comment: This `selection.on(".zoom", null);` worked for me (note the dot before zoom string)

Answer (score 1):

Another way that I found to work is to set the zoom's extent and `.extent` and `translateExtent` to the width and height element ( thus disabling the zoom altogether ). And of course to set the `scaleExtent` to [1,1].

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
userMapSvg.on(".zoom", null);
```